# Android onPreExecute cannot show a ProgressDialog

Tags: android, android-asynctask

So, I have my `AsyncTask` as below:

```
private class AsyncRetriever extends AsyncTask<IotdHandler,Void,IotdHandler>{
        ProgressDialog pDialog;
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute(){
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(getApplicationContext());
            pDialog.setMessage(getResources().getString(R.string.toast_msg1));
            pDialog.show();
        }
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

This is an inner class of the `MainActivity`. However, LogCat flags `pDialog.show()` as an error.
It says, `Unable to start activity ComponentInfo.`

**How do I solve this?**

Comment: I dont see any problem in this code dude.I have used this same piece of code so many times.

Comment: use `pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this)`. and what is the error?

Comment: *Update* `MainActivity.this` solves the problem.

Comment: Try with `ProgressDialog pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A ProgressDialog needs an Activity Context. Try this:

```
pDialog = new ProgressDialog(YourActivity.this);
```

Comment: Tried, worked. Just for information `getApplicationContext()` should do the same as what u said, right ?

Comment: @LittleChild check this for details http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7298731/when-to-call-activity-context-or-application-context

Comment: I think this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7298731/when-to-call-activity-context-or-application-context) makes this question clear.

Answer (score 1):

```
private class AsyncRetriever extends AsyncTask<IotdHandler,Void,IotdHandler>{
    ProgressDialog pDialog;
Context mcontext;
public AsyncRetriever(Context c){
   mcontext=c
}
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute(){
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(mcontext);
        pDialog.setMessage(getResources().getString(R.string.toast_msg1));
        pDialog.show();
    }
```

pass the context of calling class in this constructor